# Flask-security override Flask-login endpoint

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-login, flask-admin

I make a tuition payment app using **Flask**, and using **Flask-admin** for school operator who manages the payment, and using **Flask-login** for the parent account who want to pay their children tuition.

The problem is when the parent tries to login with their account with **Flask-login**, it always redirects to the **Flask-admin** login page.

This is the parent dashboard code:

```
from flask_login import login_required

@app.route('/parent_dashboard')
@login_required
def parent_dashboard():
    children_data = db.session.query(Student.id, Student.name).filter_by(parent_id=current_user.id).all()
    return render_template('parent_dashboard.html', children_data=children_data)
```

and here is parent login code:

```
@app.route('/parent_login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def parent_login():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('parent_dashboard'))
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = Parent.query.filter_by(email=form.email.data).first()
        if user is None or not user.check_password(form.password.data):
            return redirect(url_for('parent_login'))
        next_page = request.args.get('next')
        if not next_page or url_parse(next_page).netloc != '':
            next_page = url_for('parent_dashboard')
        return redirect(next_page)
    return render_template('login.html', form=form)
```

and this is the config file for **URL** Flask-admin

```
SECURITY_URL_PREFIX = "/admin_school"
SECURITY_LOGIN_URL = "/login_admin/"
SECURITY_POST_LOGIN_VIEW = "/admin_school/"
```

and maybe it will be more clearer if I showing image for this, and here is the parent login page:
[image]
and when the parent account try to login which is using **Flask-login**, instead of it go to **parent dashboard page**, it redirect to the **Flask-admin** login page:
[image]
But as we can see in the URL on **next** parameter:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/admin_school/login_admin/?next=%2Fparent_dashboard
```

it still have the **`parent_dashboard`** argument.

So, what's wrong with my code, why do Flask-admin override the Flask-login..?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: It would be helpful to see more of the code, as there are several places the error could be which aren't included in your question. We don't see anything about how Flask-Admin is set up, nor the templates. Do you have a link to a GitHub repository?